# POCOs; Persistance Ignorance and DAL dependencies (NHibernate)

Tags: c#, .net, database, nhibernate, repository

What does really **POCO** mean, in respect to **dependencies**?

With NHibernate; child collections are retrieved as  **NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag<>**. This is what I here mean by "dependencies"; If I try to save/update an object graph, the DAL will already have it's "opinion" about what & how I'm trying to persist it.

Initially, I thought that requesting a POCO would carry **no depencencies** to the DAL, repository, ORM *(unsure what is correct term in this perspective)*. But now I'm confused, as I'm thinking maybe it just means that the POCO class has no **persistence methods**; And that retrieving a POCO object graph may still carry such dependencies?

So when you talk about POCO, what do you really mean? Can a POCO have these type of dependencies, and **if it may AND may not**, how do you "by name" distinguish those?

A POCO that "has no such dependencies" seems more like a DTO, in some respect, but can have behavior, so it's not a DTO after all.

Also, just to be 100% sure: I assume a DTO would be persistent ignorant AND have "no dependencies" ?

*Maybe "dependencies" is not the proper word to use, so in case correct me. I hope my question is still comprehensible.*

---

**EDIT1:**

With some further thinking; Maybe my assumption that the ...PersistentGenericBag brought with it some "dependencies" is wrong (?)  Probably it's just a type, and nothing more magical. And further; that the only dependencies the objects have to NH, are via the ISessions, which of course, we have control over.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POCO are classes that does not have any dependencies on frameworks or any other infrastructure class. Well, NHibernate DOES use the `PersistentGenericBag` but your POCO will only reference an `IList` class.

For your POCO, it does't matter if this instance will be a `List`, a `ReadOnlyList` or a `PersistentGenericBag`, he will treat it as an `IList` but will have other behaviour that is not up to him deal with.

By the way, if you're mapping your Domain Objets with annotations you know have a clearly dependency to the ORM.

Comment: Cheers! I'm mapping with FluentNH. I see your point that it's similar type of List. But it seems like it means I need to pay some attention to "how" I perform CRUD operations, as NHibernate can be reluctant to certain things. But this I still don't know so much about, I'm working with such CRUD exceptions atm, so maybe there are more advantages than disadvantages when I understand how that works.

Answer (score 1):

Having no dependencies on your objects with regards to your 'DAL' is quite an utopia.
However, the way NHibernate has solved it, comes quite close IMHO.

IMHO, the term POCO means that your entities (domain objects) should not have to inherit from a certain base class, or implement some interface in order for your DAL to work.
This is the case with NHibernate.  However, indeed NHibernate requires some extra classes for collections (like the Iese.Set class), but this is mostly because the .NET framework didn't have a 'Set' class at that time.
NHibernate uses its own collection classes, but in most of the cases, you -the developer- are not troubled with that.

When following the Domain Driven Design principles, your entities can be POCO's, however your entities are certainly not just DTO's.   An entity should be a representation of how that entity looks like in the real world, with data and behaviour.

A DTO should indeed be persistant ignorant, since it is an object that can be used to transfer data between layers.  One of the 2 layers should not necessarly be your DAL.  You can use a DTO for instance to transfer data from your business layer to your view-layer.

Comment: As for lists, it's really transparent. I usually use `IList` for all my collections.  nhibernate can then use whatever implementation it like, my code do not really care. As I see it there are no dependences for my POCOs.

Comment: Thanks! What I thought was that when using a DTO (NHibernate->DTO->BusinessPOCO), then by design, the POCO has "no dependencies". If using NHibernate->BusinessPOCO, then the POCO may(?) have dependencies.  I put a (?) on may, as:  Does it "have to", or can I "easily" decide this by the way I write my repositories?

Comment: @jgauffin: note that there's a semantic difference between IList and ISet; nHibernate treats them differently.

Comment: Yes. ISet demands unique items while IList do not. But it doesnt really matter if you design your db/repository properly.

Comment: It does matter in some cases, even if your DB is designed properly.  (For instance an association of items that contains another association).